# Create object in many-to-one relationship in Spring (Not-null property references a transient value)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-one, transient

I am trying to create an object **Activity** which is part of a many to one relationship with **Course** (a course can have multiple activities).

When I try to persist the new Activity object i get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : app.model.activity.Activity.course -> app.model.Course
```

I'll include the related code.

**Controller POST Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/activities", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Void> createActivity(@Valid @RequestBody ActivityPostDto activityPostDto, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

    CourseDto courseDto = courses.findById(activityPostDto.getCourseId());
    Course course = modelMapper.map(courseDto, Course.class);
    if (course==null){
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    ActivityType activityType = activityService.findType(activityPostDto.getTypeId());
    if (activityType==null){
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    Activity activity = new Activity();
    activity.setCourse(course);
    activity.setType(activityType);
    activity.setName(activityPostDto.getName());
    activity.setDate(new Date(activityPostDto.getDate()));
    activity = activityService.add(activity);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/activities/{id}").buildAndExpand(activity.getId()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**ActivityPostDto Class**

```
public class ActivityPostDto implements Item {

   @NotNull
   private Long date;

   @NotNull
   private String name;

   @NotNull
   private Long courseId;

   @NotNull
   private Long typeId;

   ...

}
```

**Activity Class**

```
public class Activity implements Item, Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   ...

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
   private ActivityType type;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", nullable = false)
   @JsonSerialize(using = CustomCourseSerializer.class)
   private Course course;

   ...
}
```

**Course class**

```
public class Course implements Item, Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   ...

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Activity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
   @JsonSerialize(using = CustomActivityListSerializer.class)
   private List<Activity> activities;

   ...
}
```

I've read a bit about this problem but I can't find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you share the code of CourseDto and courses repository?

Comment: just a guess: Have you tried removing `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`? check this blog that says that it loads `Activitiy`'s that have no corresponding `Course` in Session but only in DB: http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/#Hibernate_FetchMode_3A_SUBSELECT

Comment: The CourseDto has exactly the same structure as Course, but without the annotations.The courses service makes a call to the repository's findOne method from the PagingAndSortingRepository implemented automatically by Spring.

Comment: I need FetchMode.SUBSELECT because in the course has other many-to-many relationships as well, and the results won't be returned in JSON if this fetchmode is not set. I'll try without to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, `Course` doesn't contain an `id`.

You can do something like this:

```
// it can be changed to check existence of id
CourseDto courseDto = courses.findById(activityPostDto.getCourseId());
if (courseDto ==null){
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

Course course = new Course();
course.setId(activityPostDto.getCourseId()) ;

Activity activity = new Activity();
activity.setCourse(course);
activity = activityService.add(activity);
```

Comment: You were correct. I've debugged the application and I found out that the modelMapper wasn't trasfering the id between CourseDto and Course because the Course object didn't had a setter for the id property. I've added the setter and now everything is working as it should. Thank you for putting me on the right track.